# Passing string parameter with alphabetic characters to a javascript function as argument fails

Tags: c#, javascript, string, function, parameters

i tried to call a javascript function from codebehind(c#.net) with a **parameter string parameter consisting of all alphabetic characters** (eg: function1("fsdadfa");) and failed to get it worked. But when i changed the alphabetic characters with all numeric ones (eg:function1("12234");) it worked.

My code is as follows:

i used **string.Format** to call the function. My code is as follows:

```
     string.Format("javascript:OpenNewsletter1({0},{1})",reader.GetInt("Id").ToString(),"dcsfs")
```

the problem arises with the 2nd parameter.

Any body know why it happened? if so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode it and use quotes:

```
string.Format("javascript:OpenNewsletter1({0}, '{1}')",
    reader.GetInt("Id").ToString(),
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("dcsfs"))
```

Notice the single quotes around the second parameter as well as encoding it because if the value contains special characters it might break your code.

Comment: Thank you..it worked!!!!!!!!!! Can you explain me why it worked for "1233" type parameter?

Comment: @Harun, it's because the 1233 parameter is numeric, so you don't need to surround it with quotes like string parameters.

Comment: ok... but "1233" is also a string right? it should not have worked for that also..

Comment: @Harun, it will depend on what your `OpenNewsletter1` function expects as first parameter. Note that there is a difference between `OpenNewsletter1(1233, 'dcsfs')` and `OpenNewsletter1('1233', 'dcsfs')`. Ini the first case the function takes a numeric as first argument while in the second a string.

Comment: @harun: no, you were sending no quotes, just 1233 - which was interpreted as an integer, and dcsfs, which was interpreted as a variable name.

Comment: @Darin, "it will depend on what your OpenNewsletter1 function expects as first parameter"- I'm not clear with this statement as my first parameter is also a string..

Comment: @Harun, in javascript you have different types: numeric and strings. For example with a numeric type you can perform arithmetic operations directly. If your javascript function expects string as first parameter then you need to surround it with quotes the same way as we did with the second parameter.

Comment: ok..Now i understood. so javaScript function takes "1234" without single quotes as numeric..  and can't determine the type "asdf" without single quotes...right?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is inserted in the format string as-is, so

```
string.Format("javascript:OpenNewsletter1({0},{1})",123,"dcsfs")
```

yields

```
javascript:OpenNewsletter1(123,dcsfs)
```

where javascript interprets `dcsfs` as a variable name.

Try

```
string.Format("javascript:OpenNewsletter1({0},'{1}')",123,"dcsfs")
```

which will yield

```
javascript:OpenNewsletter1(123,'dcsfs')
```

that javascript will know to handle as a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to add quotes around the string (parameter `{1}`) for javascript:

```
string.Format(
   "javascript:OpenNewsletter1({0},\"{1}\")",
   reader.GetInt("Id").ToString(),
   "dcsfs")
```